# Prime numbers calculation with python

Tags: python

I know, there are a lot of questions about prime numbers already, but I don't ask for a code. I just want to know, what is wrong with the mine (I hope comments would help you understand, what I'm doing):

```
from math import ceil

def isPrimeNumber (n, out='short'): #Checks, whether n is a prime number
    answer = 'Yes'
    for p in range(2, int(ceil(n**0.5))+1): #Checks all numbers lower than 
                                            #SQRT(n), if they are divisors of n
        if n%p == 0:    #If p is a divisor, n isn't prime
            answer = 'No'  
            if out == 'verbose':
                print 'Least divisor is', p
            return False
            break
    if answer == 'Yes': #If there isn't a p, that is a divisor, n is prime
        if out == 'verbose':
            print 'No divisors except for 1 and', str(n)+'!'
        return True   

def primeNumbers (start = 1, stop = 1000, numbers = 0):
    N = stop
    if numbers == 0: #Calculates all prime numbers in N numbers in a row
                     #(N=1000 -> calculates all prime numbers in 1000 numbers,
                     #by default from 1 to 997)
        primes = []
        for i in range(start, N+1):
            if isPrimeNumber(i) == True:
                primes.append(i)
    elif numbers == 1: #Calculates N prime numbers in a row 
                       #(N=1000 -> calculates 1000 prime numbers)
        primes = [start]
        i = len(primes)
        j = 1
        while i <= N: #Stops, when we get N prime numbers - doesn't work!
            n = max(primes) + 1
            while j != 'stop':
                if isPrimeNumber(n, out='short') == True:
                    primes.append(n)
                    i = i + 1
                    j = 'stop' #Stops nested cycle, when reached 
                               #the first prime number
                else:
                    n = n + 1
    else:
        print 'Wrong input! 3rd number in function call must be either 0 or 1'
    return primes
```

Function isPrimeNumber() works fine. Function primeNumbers works fine as well, when numbers=0. But if numbers=1, then, as it seems, one of the cycles never stops, I can't understan why...

Comment: As a start, you should follow PEP 8 to write more readable code.

Comment: Also, don't use strings like `'Yes'` or `'No'`, but prefer booleans (`True` and `False`).

Comment: I'm trying to follow it, but I've just started programming and first I'd like to learn to write the working code. But thank you!
Um, don't know, why I didn't use booleans there, as I use them in a different place in the same program... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your j variable is eventually set to 'stop', and then never set back again, so the `while j!='stop'` only works the first time.

```
    # don't initialize j here
    while i <= N: #Stops, when we get N prime numbers - doesn't work!
        n = max(primes) + 1
        j = 1  #initialize it here
        while j != 'stop':
            if isPrimeNumber(n, out='short') == True:
                primes.append(n)
                i = i + 1
                j = 'stop' #Stops nested cycle, when reached 
                           #the first prime number
            else:
                n = n + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop right here:

```
    while i <= N:
        n = max(primes) + 1 ### resetting `n'!
        while j != 'stop':
            if isPrimeNumber(n, out='short') == True:
                ...
                j = 'stop'
            else:
                n = n + 1
```

Once `j` is set to `'stop'`, you never change it back. Once this happens, the inner `while` effectively becomes a no-op, turning the outer `while` into an infinite loop.

Comment: Um, so the outer loop is infinite? But, actually, every time it works, n = max(primes) + 1 is different, as primes should get a new number, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I'd clean it up a bit...

```
from math import ceil
def isprime (n,out="short"):
    answer = True
    for p in range(2,int(ceil(n ** 0.5)) + 1):
        if n % p == 0:
            answer = False
            if out == "verbose":
                print "Least Divisor: " + str(p)
            return False
    if answer:
        if out == "verbose":
            print "No Divisors (Except For 1 & " + str(n) + "!"
        return True
def primenumbers (start = 1,stop = 1000,numbers = False):
    N = stop
    if numbers:
        primes = [start]
        i = len(primes)
        j = 1
        while i <= N:
            n = max(primes) + 1
            j = true
            while j:
                if isPrimeNumber(n):
                    primes.append(n)
                    i = i + 1
                    j = false
                else:
                    n = n + 1
    else
        primes = []
        for i in range(start,N + 1):
            if isPrimeNumber(i):
                primes.append(i)
    return primes
```

I did change the actual program slightly.